# The name 'NodaTimeField' does not exist in the current context error during installation of index on RavenDB

Tags: ravendb, nodatime

I am using NodaTime's LocalDate in RavenDB index.
Here is an example of the index:

```
public class TaskIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ScheduleTask>
{
    public TaskIndex()
    {
        Map = tasks => from task in tasks
            select new
            {
                task.Name,
                PlannedStartDate = task.PlannedStartDate.AsLocalDate().Resolve(),
                PlannedDueDate = task.PlannedDueDate.AsLocalDate().Resolve()
            };

        Index(x => x.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Store(x => x.Name, FieldStorage.Yes);
        TermVector(x => x.Name, FieldTermVector.WithPositionsAndOffsets);
    }
}
```

I installed RavenDB-NodaTime bundle as described [here](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenDB-NodaTime/wiki/Installation-and-Configuration).

Here is a piece of code I use to install index:

```
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(new AssemblyName
{
    Name = "cs.Scheduling"
});
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(assembly);
var provider = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
var commands = documentStore.DatabaseCommands.ForDatabase(dbName);
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(provider, commands, documentStore.Conventions);
```

`documentStore` is configured with default database, but then I use it to install index to different (tenant) database name of which comes in `dbName`.

During the installation of the index I got an exception: `The name 'NodaTimeField' does not exist in the current context`.

I have one default database which is completely different from database I try to install index for. So basically the case is similar to one described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ravendb/8T0BEeqPiUc/tCgSOk8gm08J) but I am using standalone version of RavenDB server.

I tried to find out how I can do suggested there but was not able to do that:

```
embeddableDocumentStore.ServerIfEmbedded.Options.DatabaseLandlord.SetupTenantConfiguration += configuration =>
            {
                configuration.Catalog.Catalogs.Add(new TypeCatalog(typeof(DeleteOnConflict)));
                configuration.Catalog.Catalogs.Add(new TypeCatalog(typeof(PutOnConflict)));
            };
```

Version of RavenDB I am using is 2.5.2956.
RavenDB.Client.NodaTime - 2.5.10.

Hope for your help. Thanks.

Comment: I will investigate.  Thanks.

Comment: Is that possible that I am using too old version of RavenDB? I tried to find something related to tenant configuration in RavenDB repository and I can see that while there exist some classes in master branch they don't exist in 2.5 branch.
For example under this path https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/tree/master/Raven.Database/Server/Tenancy there are classes related to tenancy management (like DatabaseLandlord.cs and others) but they don't exist in 2.5 branch.

Comment: @MattJohnson - Sorry for confusing you. That all was my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case that was a very silly mistake. When I was installing RavenDB server some time ago I installed it into non-default destination. Later some RavenDB updates were installed into default destination (i.e. `\Program Files (x86)\RavenDB`). And when I was installing RavenDB-NodaTime bundle I put it into incorrect destination (`\Program Files (x86)\RavenDB`).

After detecting this issue and configuring RavenDB server in my correct  destination properly an error described in the heading has gone away.

Hope this answer can help somebody else.

**P.S.** Later there was a deserialization error during reading data from db (RavenDB was not aware of how to deserialize date from string in `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format to `LocalDate` object) which I fixed by calling `store.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);` after `store.Initialize();` call as [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294016/steven) suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011726/the-name-nodatimefield-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-error-during-inst/35180282#35180282).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is that your tenant database does not have the bundle "activated"  Your database document (under settings in Raven 3) should have something like

```
"Raven/ActiveBundles": "Encryption;Compression;NodaTime"
```

Also you must call

```
store.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
```

I call this after store.Initialize().  Once you do both of these things, you may have to fix existing data by re-saving your documents (not sure if there is another way).  New data will be properly stored like '2016-2-3' format which should make your index return data.